# Why is the dialog not showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog

The alert() works when the Send button is clicked but the dialog never shows.  I have been going crazy trying to figure out why this is. What am I doing wrong? Please see code below:

Thanks,
TD

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DIALOG TEST</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body onload="loadMsg()">

    <div id="dg"></div>

    <div id="#dialog_login" title="Login Status">
        <br />
        <div id="dialog_text" style="text-align: center;"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dg.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

form.html

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">TEST</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form method="post" action="javascript:msg();">  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div                       
                </form>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

dg.js

```
function msg(){
    $("#dialog_login").text('Login Successful');
    $("#dialog_login").dialog('open');
    alert('Login Successful');  
}

function loadMsg(){
    $("#dg").load("form.html");
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Any reason for using two versions of jQuery?

Comment: No errors if I am using the Chrome Developer tools correctly.  No reason for the multiple version of JQuery.  I will remove the older version and see what happens and report back

Comment: OK, remarked out each of the JQuery versions, one at a time, and the dialog still doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I changed a little bit the code, I hope this works for you

```
function msg(){
$("#dialog_text").text('Login Successful');
$("#dialog_login").dialog({
    show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 } 

  })
};
```

And you have other error

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div
```

close the div with ">"

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
```

Comment: I fixed the div and copied your js code into dg.js replacing my code there but still the dialog will not show.  Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: please comment the line in the loadMsg() function `$("#dg").load("form.html");` and try it again

Comment: I did and as expected the screen is empty since this code loads the form with the button from form.html so no button to click.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after many hours of looking at this I found the problem; I had added '#' to the id:

```
<div id="#dialog_login" title="Login Status">
```

I corrected this:

```
 <div id="dialog_login" title="Login Status">
```

Next I added this line to dg.js:

```
$('#dialog_login').dialog({autoOpen: false});
```

So dg.js looks like this now:

```
function msg(){
$('#dialog_login').dialog({autoOpen: false});
$("#dialog_login").text('Login Successful');
$("#dialog_login").dialog('open');
alert('Login Successful');  
}

function loadMsg(){
    $("#dg").load("form.html");
```

I want to thank everyone who tried to help!